# Need to pull campaign members form Salesforce to marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I need to pull the data from the campaign members object in sfdc and another custom object and then use the data for a Journey, is that possible.

Comment: Yes, you can use the [Salesforce Data Entry Source](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_salesforce_data_event.htm&type=5)

Comment: Three words for you: [Synchronised Data Sources](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_data_integration_for_your_account_with_synchronized_data_sources.htm)